# RuntimeException thrown by an install4j installer on windows XP

Tags: install4j

I have an install4j installer that works fine on windows 7 (x64), but when I try to launch the 32 bit version of the installer on a (virtual) windows xp machine, the installer crashes at startup with the following message:

[image]

The error.log contains the following:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.getScreenExecutor(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.runInProcess(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.main(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(Unknown Source)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could not load i4jinst from C:\Documents and Settings\malt\Local Settings\Temp\e4j7C.tmp_dir1409498652\i4jinst.dll, true, C:\DOCUME~1\malt\LOCALS~1\Temp\e4j7C.tmp_dir1409498652\platform.zip, true, C:\DOCUME~1\malt\LOCALS~1\Temp\e4j7C.tmp_dir1409498652\i4jinst.dll
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.platform.win32.Common.init(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.platform.win32.Registry.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.api.windows.WinRegistry.getValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.api.windows.WinRegistry.getValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.registry.Win32Registry.getValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.registry.InstallRegistry.getValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.registry.InstallRegistry.getAllInstallationDirs(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.registry.InstallRegistry.getInstallationDir(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.config.InstallerConfig.getInitialInstallationDirectory(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.config.InstallerConfig.getInstallationDirectory(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl.getInstallationDirectory(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.InstallerContextImpl.initUpdateInstallation(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.InstallerContextImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.InstallerWizardScreenExecutor.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Edit: for reference, I'm using Install4j 5.1.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a regression in 5.1.13 and is fixed in 5.1.14.